# Group by and aggregate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
 Id       User Val1 Val2
 11910115 Fred 123 -0.000137
 11910116 Fred 456 0
 11910117 Fred 789 0.0002
 11910118 Sue 101 8.7E-05
 11910119 Sue 102 0.000125
 11910120 Sue 103 0
```

The intent:

```
Select Id,User,Val1,Max(abs(val2)) val2
From MyTable
Group By User
```

What I'm after is:

```
11910117 Fred 789 0.0002
11910119 Sue 102 0.000125
```

What I'd settle for is:

```
11910117 0.0002
11910119 0.000125
```

However, I can't get around the 'is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate...'

Comment: And which one is invalid in the select list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT y.Id, y.User, y.Val1, t.MaxVal
    FROM YourTable y
        INNER JOIN (SELECT User, MAX(ABS(val2)) AS MaxVal
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY User) t
            ON y.User = t.User
                AND ABS(y.Val2) = t.MaxVal
    WHERE y.User = 'Fred'
```

Comment: Sorry I neglected to add a 'where' clause. However, if I do enter " Where y.user = Fred" I get the same 3 rows returned:
 11910115 Fred 123 -0.000137
 11910116 Fred 456 0
 11910117 Fred 789 0.0002

Comment: @JonV: My mistake. You'd want to work off of `User` instead of `Id`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JonV: Glad to help. Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Every field that is not an aggregated should appear in the group by. So assuming you want to aggregate val1 too:

```
Select Id, User, max(Val1) val1, max(abs(val2)) val2
From MyTable
Group By Id, User
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants - he doesn't want the maximum value for val1, but the value for val1 that belongs to the maximum value for val2.

Comment: `max(val1)` is not the desired outcome based on the expected results given in the question.

Comment: I made an assumption there. val1 was not aggregated at all, though it seamed to be in the expected results. It is max for 'Fred', so I assumed it might have been a typo for Sue. Could change it to `decode (User, 'Fred', max(val1), avg(val1))`, but that didn't make much sense either. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id, User, Val1, Val2
from MyTable t1
where not exists
(
   select * 
   from MyTable t2
   where t2.Id != t1.Id
   and   t2.User = t1.User
   and   abs(t2.Val2) > abs(t1.Val2) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
SELECT t.id, t.user, t.val1, t.val2
FROM mytable t
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT user, MAX(ABS(val2)) AS max
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY user) q ON t.user = q.user AND ABS(t.val2)=q.max
```

Not sure about how efficient this would be on your table, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id,
       [User],
       Val1,
       Val2
from (
      select Id,
             [User],
             Val1,
             Val2,
             row_number() over(partition by [User] order by abs(Val2) desc) as rn
      from YourTable
      -- where ... goes here
     ) as T
where rn = 1
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114300/